# Post method in python for mongo db

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

Connecting Python to MongoDB. Performing crud operations, Get is working but Post is not working.
Below is the code for the form that has textfields and submit button.

```
 @app.route('/submit-form', methods=['POST'])
    def submit_form():
        data = request.json 
        print(data)
        collection.insert_one({
        'name': data.get('name', ''),
        'age': data.get('age', 0),
        'location': data.get('location', ''),
        'qualification': data.get('qualification', '')
    })
        return jsonify({'message': 'Form data submitted successfully!'}), 201
```

Comment: This is not a `ReactJS` question. To get answers quickly, use the right tag. Use `flask` instead. This is Python Flask code.

Comment: How is it even working at all when `request` is not defined?